# Handle different states

Tags: scala, apache-spark, state, spark-streaming

I was wondering if it was possible to maintain radically different states across an application? For example, have the `update function` of the first state call the one from the second state?

I do not recall going through any such example, nor did I find any counter indication... Based on the example from https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html, I know of no reason why I wouldn't be able to have different `trackStateFunc`s with different `State`s, and still update those thanks to their `Key`, as shown below:

```
def firstTrackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, 
                        key: String, 
                        value: Option[Int], 
                        state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
    val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
    val output = (key, sum)
    state.update(sum)
    Some(output)
}
```

and

```
def secondTrackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, 
                         key: String, 
                         value: Option[Int], 
                         state: State[Int]): Option[(String, Long)] = {
    // disregard problems this example would cause
    val dif = value.getOrElse(0) - state.getOption.getOrElse(0L) 
    val output = (key, dif)
    state.update(dif)
    Some(output)
}
```

I think this is possible but still remain unsure. I would like someone to validate or invalidate this assumption...

Comment: You want the input to be the same, but have the ability to update one state inside another? Or would you want to get the state from the first based on key, and use that to update the state in two?

Comment: I don't necessarily want the input to be the same, but the states to be completely different (like a one field state and multi field other). Being able to update the second inside the first state would great, but isn't the main purpose. In fact, I would like to know if I can update radically different states in the same application (through different update functions)? Is it clearer for you?

Comment: I think so. States are isolated, you can't interact between them inside different `mapWithState` functions. What you *can* do is chain those states together and pass them as the value to the next `mapWithState`, but I don't think that's what you want to do.

Comment: That's a good tip to know. Last attempt on my part to check if I managed to make myself clear: does my state DStream, that acts like key-value store, can store different value types among my states? Thus having completely different states?

Comment: It can, if you use different `mapWithState` calls on the `DStream`. A single `mapWithState` can't hold multiple states, unless the type you're storing inside that `State` is some composite object which contains all the different types of state you want to hold.

Comment: Thank you, this completely answers my question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov could you summarize your answer as a response to this question for wipman to accept? That's for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: @maasg That's a good idea. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if it was possible to maintain radically different
>   states across an application?

Every call to `mapWithState` on a `DStream[(Key, Value)]` can hold one `State[T]` object. This `T` needs to be the same for every invocation of `mapWithState`. In order to use different states, you can either chain `mapWithState` calls, where one's `Option[U]` is anothers input, or you can have split the `DStream` and apply a different `mapWithState` call to each one. You cannot, however, call a different `State[T]` object inside another, as they are isolated from one another, and one cannot mutate the state of the other.

Answer (score 1):

@Yuval gave a great answer to chain mapWithState functions. However, I have another approach. Instead of having two mapWithState calls, you can put both the sum and the diff in the same State[(Int, Int)].

In this case, you would only need one mapWithState functions where you could update both the things. Something like this:

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, 
                   key: String, 
                   value: Option[Int], 
                   state: State[(Long, Int)]): Option[(String, (Long, Int))] =
{
    val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
    val dif = value.getOrElse(0) - state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
    val output = (key, (sum, diff))
    state.update((sum, diff))
    Some(output)
}
```